# Block POST requests from specific IPs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It doesn't matter how hard I try. My htaccess doesn't make any sense. I want to block POST requests coming from specific IPs.

This code works and blocks all POST requests:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

I just need to add conditions to blacklist IPs like follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =123.123.123.123 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =222.222.222.222 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =111.111.111.111
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

On paper it should work but in reality it doesn't. When I POST from one of the blacklisted IP (e.g. 123.123.123.123) the block doesn't trigger.

What is wrong with my code?

Before you ask I can't use Allow, Deny and yes, I'm using real IP addresses to run tests. I just don't want to publish them :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dots from IP addresses.

> "." Matches any single character

You can try below code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.123\.123\.123$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^222\.222\.222\.222$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111\.111\.111\.111$
    RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Reference : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regexvocab